# Python Pattern Design

Tags: python

I'm trying to achieve the pattern below.
Got as far as doing the first line, then I have no clue how to code the rest of the pattern.

[image: pattern image]

Here's what I've done so far:

```
#Timothy Shek
from graphics import*

#open Graph Window

def main():

    win = GraphWin("Example",100,100)
    x = 7
    y = 7
    radius = 5


    while x<=30 :
        centre = Point(x,y)
        circle1 = Circle(centre,radius)
        circle1.setFill("red")
        circle1.draw(win)
        x = x+10

    while x>=35 and x<=65 :
        centre = Point(x+5,y)
        circle2 = Circle(centre,radius)
        circle2.setFill("red")
        circle2.draw(win)
        x = x+10

    print(x)

    while x>=67:
        centre = Point(x+10,y)
        circle1 = Circle(centre,radius)
        circle1.setFill("red")
        circle1.draw(win)
        x = x+10

main()
```

Comment: This really isn't what is meant by design patterns.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the title, hopefully thats better explained

Comment: You can also draw lines 3,4,6,7 and 9 correctly already. For the missing lines, just think about how you could describe it to somebody who's using pen and paper.

Comment: It might help to delegate the sub-patterns (the one white circle and the 8 red circles around it) to a separate function. Then you just need to call that function with appropriate arguments 9 times.

Answer (score 1):

I got it guys, thanks
Heres the solution

```
#Timothy Shek
from graphics import*

#open Graph Window
def main():
    win = GraphWin("Patch2" ,100,100)
    for x in (5, 15, 25, 40,50,60,75,85,95):
        for y in (5, 15, 25, 40,50,60,75,85,95):
            c = Circle(Point(x+2,y), 5)
            d = Circle(Point(x+2,y), 5)
            c.draw(win)
            d.draw(win)
            c.setFill("Red")
            d.setFill("Red")
            if x==15 or x==50 or x== 85:
                if y==15 or y==50 or y== 85:
                    c2 = Circle(Point(x+2,y),5)
                    c2.draw(win)
                    c2.setFill("White")

main()
```

Comment: Aren't `c` and `d` the exact same Circle?

Answer (score 0):

While there is nothing wrong with your solution, this is a bit more performant

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Patch2" ,100,100)
    coords = [5, 15, 25, 40, 50, 60, 75, 85, 95]
    centers = set([coords[i] for i in range(1, len(coords), 3)])
    for i in xrange(len(coords)):
        for j in xrange(i+1):
            x, y = (coords[i], coords[j])
            c1 = Circle(Point(x+2,y), 5)
            c2 = Circle(Point(y+2,x), 5)
            c1.draw(win)
            c2.draw(win)
            if x in centers and y in centers:
                c1.setFill("White")
                c2.setFill("White")
            else:
                c1.setFill("Red")
                c2.setFill("Red")

main()
```

---

#### Update: "Better" version

And since I got bored and I liked this problem (yes, I program when I'm bored) I made a fully parameter-ized version which you can do some fun stuff with, like.

[image: Blue and white]

Probably over your head :) But maybe you learn something from it, so I'm posting it.

```
from graphics import *

def drawPattern(scale):
    # Inner method: Draw a square of circles given the top-left point
    def drawSquare(win, xCoord, yCoord, squareSize=30, numCircles=3, scale=1, scaleCircles=False, outer_color="Red", inner_color="White"):

        # Overwrite the default scaling
        if scale > 1:
            squareSize *= scale
            if scaleCircles:
                numCircles *= scale

        radius = squareSize/(numCircles*2) # Divide by 2 since it's the radius
        from math import sqrt, floor
        centerDiff = (2*radius) * floor(sqrt(numCircles)) # Used for drawing off-color circles

        # xrange uses an exclusive stop value, so go one value past to make inclusive
        for x in xrange(radius, squareSize+radius, radius*2):
            for y in xrange(squareSize-radius, x-radius, -radius*2):
                c1 = Circle(Point(x+xCoord+2,y+yCoord), radius)
                c2 = Circle(Point(y+yCoord+2,x+xCoord), radius)
                c1.draw(win)
                c2.draw(win)

                if (centerDiff < x < squareSize - centerDiff) and (centerDiff < y < squareSize - centerDiff):
                    c1.setFill(inner_color)
                    c2.setFill(inner_color)
                else:
                    c1.setFill(outer_color)
                    c2.setFill(outer_color)

    win = GraphWin("Patch2 (x{})".format(scale), 100*scale,100*scale)
    coords = [0, 35, 70]
    for x in coords:
        for y in coords:
            drawSquare(win, x*scale, y*scale, scale=scale) # normal (boring) version
            # drawSquare(win, x*scale, y*scale, scale=scale, scaleCircles=True, outer_color="Blue") # Picture version


def main():
    drawPattern(3)

main()
```